# how to input Japanese to TextArea in JavaFX on Linux

Tags: linux, javafx, centos7, kde-plasma

I'm beginner of JavaFX, I'm developing JavaFX Application using CentOS7(I use KDE), but I can't input Japanese to TextArea/TextField.

when I type some word, TextArea/TextField show only English even if I set "KEY-MAP=jp106".

there is same JavaFX Application on Windows, I can input Japanese to TextField/TextArea when I execute that JavaFX application on Windows.

I use ibus-kkc on CentOS7, I can input Japanese on website(FireFox), memo(KWrite), and I can input Japanese Comment in my Eclipse on CentOS7.

I've searched any solution on Website for 1 week but I couldn't find some tips on Website written by Japanese(because I'm Japanese, I apologize my terrible English).

Does anyone know good way to solve?

Thanks!

I use:

```
CentOS7

jdk-11.0.4

javafx-sdk-11.0.2

Eclipse ide 2018-09

ibus-kkc

VMware Workstation 15 player
```

I changed from ibus-kkc to fcitx-Anthy but I could not input Japanese on that JavaFX application.

Comment: I could copy and past Japanese words from Kwrite to Textfield/TextArea.

Answer (score 3):

I found that solution by myself.

I read release note about JavaFX11, and I had to input processing of changing GTK version 
forcibly when I execute JavaFX application.

https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/jfx-11/doc-files/release-notes-11.md#release-notes-for-javafx-11

when I execute it, I put,

$startx

$cd (directory that exist class file)

$java -Djdk.gtk.version=2 ...

I could execute correctly.

Thanks!